# PhpStorm: undo changes replaced by global replace

Tags: phpstorm

I have replaced globally in PhpStorm with <kbd>Shift + R</kbd> combination but by some reason it didn't match a case and did wrong replacement in the whole project.

Is it possible to undo the last operation and back it to the last state?

Comment: Use Local History: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/local-history.html

Comment: You can also simply hit "Undo" after this and IDE would revert global (ctrl+shit+R) replacement operation.